# Small in-memory database for making temporary operation on a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a small part for my ASP.NET MVC website the will require the following steps:

1. Query my SQL Server DB for data from a particular table.
2. For each data row returned take that data and run another query (stored procedure) that returns some values.
3. take those values and run a calculation.

now that I have that calculation I will need to take it and store it along with some other data items from the first query in-memory (or, not if you think otherwise) and filter and sort. after filtering and sorting displaying the results to the user.

What do you guys recommend doing for such a scenario where you need to have an in-memory data representation that will have to be manipulated? should I just stick with DataTable? I found a component called QueryADataSet which allows running querys against .NET DataSets and DataTables - does anyone knows it? how about using that kind of solution? recommended?

would love to hear your thoughts...

Thanks

Comment: I'd avoid running SPROCs in a loop. Loop of 100 items = 100 queries per user per page load. Doesn't scale very well... I'd either do what Remus states, or if the SPROC takes a little bit of time, then possibly use a denormalized table where you store all the calculated data... so then you are just hitting a static table that has all your data.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev what if it's supposed to be in real time?

Comment: Then you'll prob have to do what Remus says. If you are making the user wait through a loop of queries... then it probably wouldn't be terrible (it will definitely be faster) to just run those calcs on the initial query. Or you could just keep that denormalized table to-do-date like updating rows with a trigger whenever data changes... but that could get messy or confusing.

Comment: how bad is having calculation on the server side?

Comment: I personally don't have issue with it... IMO that's what the [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event is for... manipulating the data before it is rendered. I was just referring to not doing step 2). It really depends on what you are doing... but there's some stuff you aren't going to want to do in SQL. Like if the values need to get passed through a C# function. I wouldn't try to replicate that in SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Change the website to behave as follows:

1. Send a single query to SQL that uses set operations to apply the calculations to the relevant data and return the result.

This is not a joke nor irony. Using the app server for doing 'sort' and 'filter' is not the proper place. Aside from the lack of an adequate toolset, there are issues around consitency/caching behavior. Data manipulation belongs to the back end, this is why you use SQL and not a key-value store. Not even mentioning the counter-pattern of 'retrieve a set and then call DB for each row'.

Comment: Yes, but there's another step that has to do with the calculation those values has to go though... which is written in .NET - is it good practice to do calculations on Database Server?

Comment: I just found this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19954/Execute-NET-Code-under-SQL-Server-2005 saying I can run .NET class methods from a SQL Server database (2005 and up) - what your thoughts about this? is this good practice / performance? if so I could move all my calculation to the database server easily and only query the db once.

Comment: SQLCLR is a good solution for porting .Net based code math calculations in the DB engine.

Answer (score 0):

If the processing cannot be performed on the database server, then **LINQ** is a good toolset to filter and sort data in the application.